# How to add a banner/label to redoc

Tags: openapi, redoc

Looking at the Redoc demo and they have used a "Webhook" label beside their title but I couldn't figure out how to implement it specifically for other labels. How would I be able to implement this to show a "Beta" label? [image]

Comment: Does this help https://redocly.com/docs/settings/labels/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a way to accomplish this. What I ended up doing is adding a label in the description which supports html.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think Redoc provides the capability to put customized label beside operation title (summary).

The *webhook* marker shown in your screenshot represents the "New pet" is not a normal API operation but a webhook. Please read [here](https://redocly.com/docs/api-reference-docs/specification-extensions/x-webhooks/) for how does Redoc support webhooks.

If you want to know more about webhooks, you could read this [post](https://codeburst.io/what-are-webhooks-b04ec2bf9ca2).

> Webhooks provide a mechanism where by a server-side application can
> notify a client-side application when a new event (that the
> client-side application might be interested in) has occurred on the
> server.